# Hiding NLog With static property returning class instance

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I am trying to break away direct dependency of NLog from my code. So if in the future i decided to use another logging library, it will be painless.
What I did is as following,

```
 internal class Logger
{
    private NLog.Logger _NLogInstance;

    internal static Logger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return new Logger();
        }
    }

    public Logger()
    {
        LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
        _NLogInstance = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public void Trace(string message)
    {
        _NLogInstance.Trace(message);
    }

    public void Debug(string message)
    {
        _NLogInstance.Debug(message);
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
        _NLogInstance.Info(message);
    }

    public void Warn(string message)
    {
        _NLogInstance.Warn(message);
    }

    public void Error(Exception ex, string message)
    {
        _NLogInstance.Error(ex, message);
    }

    public void Fatal(Exception ex, string message)
    {
        _NLogInstance.Fatal(ex, message);
    }
}
```

As you can see, to use my Logger one only need to do so,

```
Logger.Instance.Fatal(ex, ex.Message);
```

So, the real implementation of NLog is somehow hidden from the user of Logger. If tomorrow I need to use Log4net, i will only need to change my implementation in Logger class.

Is there any potential problem of doing so? Because I don't see people doing this anywhere. Or are there any better way?

Comment: " If tomorrow I need to use Log4net" It's a well know anti-pattern: You Ain't Gonna Need It. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html

Comment: @Oscar mind to explain more? What i can see is, if i don't do this, i will be tight to NLog.

Comment: So? What's the problem? Do you think that the ability to change log provider is a real functional requisite of your software? Have you ever heard of any project switching their log provider?

Comment: I don't know. If tomorrow there is a new logging library far more superior and able to do something NLog cannot, we might want to switch. Isn't it always to good to loosely couple your code? Or put it in other words. Can i apply this practice for other similar case?

Comment: You don't know, but I will tell you: It's probably in a 99,9% that it wont ever never happens. It's better to use your efforts in real implementation an not in this trivial details that only take you to over-engineering, increase complexity and degrade performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with the comments. You probably won't need to switch to another logging library and if you do, it's because the new library is so clever and works in another way, why you will need to change your abstraction anyway.

If you insist on wrapping you [Common Logging .NET](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging) instead. It's an abstraction on top of pretty much all of the major logging frameworks. This way you don't need to write the abstraction yourself.

Comment: Thanks Thomas and Oscar. Indeed trying to decouple away the Logger is over-engineer. Additionally, NLog recommend to have one logger per class. This will defeat the purpose of wrapping it, which make it one logger per app. However, forget about logger, I am still interested to know if the suggested implementation in my question make sense. Can I use it for things other than the logger. I going to mark this as the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Terrence It could make sense. If you want to log other things like performance metrics etc., the class could contain that as well. But I think that you will quickly run into problems when breaking single responsibility like that. Better to have separate classes for different responsibilities.